# What's the preferred sequence to read Effective, More Effective & Effective Modern C++ (and STL)?

Tags: c++, effective-c++

I understand that More Effective C++ is an expansion of Effective C++, while Effective Modern C++ focuses on C++11 & 14. Being a newbie to the language and just starting out with these books, should I read Effective Modern after the first two? Also, where should Effective STL fit in?

What is the preferred sequence to reading the above books, in the sense that each book is building on the content of the prior books? (Assuming everything inside is new to me?)

Additionally, is Effective Modern C++ considered an unofficial next edition to Effective C++?

Comment: I'd love to see answers to this question. But I suspect that this question will be closed due to current scope of SO. Hopefully, there is somewhere else that this is still on-topic.

Comment: @tinlyx That's why I did my best to word it so that the answer is not opinion-based (I think this is more relevant to you now so read it first), or reader-dependent (if you're new, read this first. If you are a veteran in the industry, skip to that). I eliminated the latter by explicitly assuming everything is new to me. My question is seeking to know if there are dependencies between books, or overlaps in terms of some items in this book being more up-to-date than those in another book - more factual comparisons. If there is no issue with reading in any order, you can simply say that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An answer to this can be gleaned from the [Books, etc.](http://www.aristeia.com/books.html) summary page on Scott Meyers' website:

> Effective C++, Third Edition, 2005. Scott's flagship book, and the
>   industry's must-read second book on C++ (i.e., what you read after
>   you've learned the fundamentals of the language)

Read this first.

> More Effective C++, 1996. Still relevant after nearly 20 years!
>   Indispensable in its own right, and an invaluable companion to
>   Effective C++

Read this together with, or after, Effective C++.

> Effective Modern C++, 2014. The book on effective use of the features
>   new in “modern” C++ (i.e., C++11 and C++14). A complement to Scott’s
>   existing books

Read this once you have mastered the concepts in the other two, as it is focused on the changes in the later versions of the language.

> Effective STL, 2001. 50 specific ways to improve your use of the STL,
>   including techniques for improving performance, eliminating resource
>   leaks, avoiding portability problems, and more — all in Scott's
>   inimitable style

This one is less clear although I would suggest reading it after the first two and before the third.

Comment: Where would STL fit in? Also, will there be a Eff C++ 4th ed, or is Eff Modern already that? Would a Eff C++ 4th be considered to supercede Modern if it happens?

Comment: @thegreatjedi I added STL to my answer (although it's just a guess on my part as I haven't read that one). Scott Meyers has just announced his retirement from the C++ world so I would say there won't be a 4th edition unless someone else picks up the reins.

Comment: I see, and yeap saw the edit. Thanks!